# rsync creates a directories with the same name inside the destination folder

Tags: find, rsync

I am trying to rsync only .bin files from folders beginning with 11.* and 14.* (including sub-folders), not older than 1 day.

What I have tried so far:

`` rsync -Rarv  `find /mnt/IP/ftp/123/ -type f -mtime -1` --prune-empty-dirs --include "1[1][4]./"  --include="*.bin" --exclude="*" "/mnt/IP/ftp/123/" "/home/ftp/123/" ``

It generally worked, but Rsync has created a directory with the same name inside of destination:
/home/ftp/123/mnt/IP/ftp/123/

So I am looking for solution to re-create only folders beginning with 11.* or 14.*

Comment: The easy way out: `find ... | grep ... | rsync -av --files-from=- /home/ftp/123`

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not take the "not older than 1 day" restriction into account.

Rather than trying to [parse the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697), use `rsync` directly *from* `find`:

```
find /mnt/IP/ftp/123 -type -name '1[14].*' -prune \
    -exec rsync -av \
        --include='*.bin' --include='*/' \
        --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs {} /home/ftp/123 ';'
```

This would find the directories whose names start with either `11.` or `14.` in or under `/mnt/IP/ftp/123`.  For each such directory, it would remove the directory from the search list (with `-prune`), and then execute

```
rsync -av --include='*.bin' --include='*/' \
    --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs {} /home/ftp/123
```

where `{}` would be replaced by the pathname of the found directory.

The `rsync` command would create a subdirectory of `/home/ftp/123` with the same filename as the found directory (i.e. starting with either `11.` or `14.`) and then copy the `.bin` files.

The inclusion and exclusion patterns used with `rsync` (first match wins):

- `--include='*.bin'`: include any file whose filename ends with `.bin`.
- `--include='*/'`: include any directory. Empty directories at the target will be removed due to `--prune-empty-dirs`.
- `--exclude='*'`: exclude anything not included by the previous rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to build the set of files that satisfy your three criteria:

- Not older than one day
- Must be in directories matching `11.*` or `14.*`
- Files matching `*.bin`

and then feed that list to `rsync` for processing:

```
find mnt/IP/ftp/123/./ -mtime -1 \( -path '*/1[14].*/*' -prune \) -name '*.bin' -print0 |
    rsync -av --files-from - --from0 --prune-empty-dirs / dst/
```

I've used `-print0` and `-from0` to ensure that files with unexpected characters in their names get processed correctly. The extra `/./` in the `find` path is to indicate to `rsync` that everything before this component is to be stripped from the destination path. (If you decide to use a relative path in `find` (i.e. one that does not start with `/`) then change the `rsync` source from `/` to `.`.)

---

Example scenario

```
# All files in the example
find /mnt/IP/ftp/123/./ -type f
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./11.one/7.skip/skip.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./11.one/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./12.skip/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./14.one/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./sub/13.skip/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./sub/14.next/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./sub/14.next/skip.this
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./sub/item.bin

# Files matched by "find"
find mnt/IP/ftp/123/./ -mtime -1 \( -path '*/1[14].*/*' -prune \) -name '*.bin' -print
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./11.one/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./14.one/item.bin
/mnt/IP/ftp/123/./sub/14.next/item.bin

# Files copied by "rsync"
find /mnt/IP/ftp/123/./ -mtime -1 \( -path '*/1[14].*/*' -prune \) -name '*.bin' -print0 |
    rsync -av --files-from - --from0 --prune-empty-dirs / dst/
building file list ... done
11.one/
11.one/item.bin
14.one/
14.one/item.bin
sub/
sub/14.next/
sub/14.next/item.bin
```